# Missing methods in Google Maps API v3. How can I emulate latRadians() and lngRadians()?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to calculate the latitude and longitude radians for 2 lat,lng points in a google maps by using api v3.

In api v2 they had these methods available: **latRadians()** and **lngRadians()**

How can I emulate that same functionality in api v3?

Long story short: I need to **calculate the angle of a polyline in Google Maps API 3**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just extend for example google.maps.LatLng object to have your methods:

```
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.latRadians = function()
{
  return (Math.PI * this.lat()) / 180;
}

google.maps.LatLng.prototype.lngRadians = function()
{
  return (Math.PI * this.lng()) / 180;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conversion between radians and degrees is [a well-known mathematical function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Conversion_between_radians_and_degrees):

- `radians = (π × degrees) / 180`